# How to upload photo on facebook via javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm simply trying to upload file from computer to facebook via Javascript SDK beow is the code which I've written for uploading a image on facebook here in this I've Facebook javascript SDK as well as PHP for server side script language to handle mutipart form data to upload image , But i'm totaly unaware about how to pass image as argument for javascript Facebook SDK

```js
 <script>
         // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document

           var messageToPost;
     $(document).ready(function(){

              var  isLoaded=false;
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '455772327890425',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
  
  isLoaded=true;
      };
   
function checkIfLoaded() {
    if(isLoaded) console.log("LOADED!");
    else console.log("NOT YET!");

    return false;
  }
  
      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
       
    



   
            
   
   setTimeout(function(){alert('after set time out');login(); },2000);
   
   
    
           
   
      
   
   function login()
   {
    console.log("login called");
               
               FB.login(function (response)
               {
                   accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                   console.log("inside real login");
               
                   if (response.authResponse) {
                       //fileUpload();
       
                   
        postFB();
                       //Logout();          
                      //alert("Back to Login");
                    }
                   
                   else {  alert("Login attempt failed!");}
               } , { scope: 'email,user_photos,photo_upload,publish_actions,publish_stream' });
               
   };
   
   function postFB()
   {
                 
                  //alert("message "+ messageToPost);
      var images={}
      
       var wallPost = {
                                        message:      '<?php echo $messageToPost ?>',
                                        name        : 'SBIINTOUCH',
                                        description : 'SBIINTOUCH experience',
          height      : 70,
          width       : 60,
                source     : '<?php   echo  (basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])); ?>'
          
                 
                                  }; 
       
       
       alert(wallPost['message'] +"\n"+wallPost['source'] );
       
                 //posting in time line
                  FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                      alert(JSON.stringify(response.error)+'Error occured while posting in personal feed');
                    } else {
                      alert('Post ID: personal feed ' + response.id);
                    }
                  });
                  
                 //posting in page
                  FB.api('/512538375541360/photos', 'post', 
                          wallPost, 
                      function(response) {

                          if (!response || response.error) {
                              alert(JSON.stringify(response.error)+ "while posting in page feed");
                          } else {
                              alert('Post ID : SBI Intouch ' + response.id);
                          }
                      });
    FB.logout();
       };
   
             
     
   
            
   });
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="js/jquery-v1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-v1-8.js"></script>
        

   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script>
      
  
    
    </script>

   <?php
   echo $_POST['txta'];
   echo $_POST['loc1'];
   echo $_POST['Feedback'];
    
   
   $target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
    //msg formation
      $messageToPost = $_POST['txta'];
     
                  $city          = $_POST['loc1'];
       echo    'city  is '.$city;
      
                  $sentiment= $_POST['Feedback'];
                 
                 if($sentiment==='Good')
                  $messageToPost=$messageToPost." :) "."    #SBIInTouch".$city;
                 if($sentiment==='Neutral')
                  $messageToPost=$messageToPost." :| "."    #SBIInTouch".$city;
                 if(  $sentiment==='Bad')  
                  $messageToPost=$messageToPost." :( "."    #SBIInTouch".$city;
   
      echo    'message is '.$messageToPost;
   ?>

   
   
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload picture from computer using faacebook PHP SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763148/how-to-upload-picture-from-computer-using-faacebook-php-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'm not pretty sure, but i got the documentation :3
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/album/photos#publish

you could send the image bytes directly, or use the URL to make the Facebook server load it. :)

using js-sdk to upload the image bytes:

```js
FB.api(
    "/{album-id}/photos",
    "POST",
    {
        "source": "{image-data}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

or, using the url instead of upload the images bytes:

```js
FB.api(
    "/{album-id}/photos",
    "POST",
    {
        "url": "{image-url}"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```